# Need to export manual test runs execution results from AzureDevOps to any Format

Tags: testing, azure-devops, uat

We need to export the latest run with every step and its attachments in AzureDevOps. It is a 300 Test Cases run/execution report that needs to be approved, as we have many use cases, it is not plausible to go one run by one run and download every attachment step and print it by hand.

I tried exporting TestPlans, the export from Test Plan does not apply in this case as it does not care about the runs steps and its attachments. I do not see a solution with the new AzureDevOps run Page,

Would like to know if I am missing any configuration option or if there is an API or even product to export the data. e.g. Example one of many Runs to save in Report Many

I saw other similar questions but still missing how to export runs reports with its steps and attachment.  Image below,

[Example of one of the 300 runs to export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIPfX.png)

Many Thanks

**UPDATE:**  As I do not see any an out of the box solution I am trying to get the information from this API [ResultsAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) but I am not able yet to get the [ActionResultModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#testactionresultmodel) that includes the stepIdentifier.  Also problems downloading the attachments.

Answer (score 1):

In this AzureDevOps version there is no way to export the run steps result. Also the results API is not retrieving the step result information, I did some test with the API and it is not possible to get the testActionResultModel in the response.   The maximum that you can get is the iterations list, but there is no link between the iterations and the steps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/action%20results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#testactionresultmodel

Thank you

Comment: To get the steps on a test case you need to use the workitem API. Getting all the test results including evidence has been available via the API since TFS 2015 update 3.  I remember we hired a contractor for a few weeks specifically to have them build a tool that we could use to produce a report of all the test point results, including the steps and evidence for a test plan. ,

Answer (score 0):

You have a try with the **export** option in Test Plans. First you need to create a test plan and add all your manual test cases using query to this test plan.

You can follow the detailed steps of [Creating test plans and test suites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops).

Go to Test plans under Test Plans of your project. Then click the **3 dots** beside your test plan and selet **Export**

[image]

Then check the options you to export.

[image]

Then you will get an export of all the manual test cases included in this test plan with their steps and attachments.

[image]

Hope above helps!

Comment: Sorry, as I said I tried the export from Test Plan, it just gives the last run execution outcome but it does not export the Summary or details of the concrete run. Thanks

Comment: Hi @BjorneCode I got the same result of yours, cannot get ActionResultModel. You can report a problem [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) (click report a problem and choose azure devops). Hope the Microsoft Development team will investigate this issue and provide a fix.

Comment: I have the exact same use case.  Has anyone been able to solve this?  I am unable to use TestPlans without this ability.